# php form processing for wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress, jquery

I am adding a form to my wordpress with a custom php page template

Below is my wordpress page template php code:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Form
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="content">

    <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <div class="entry">

        Welcome <?php echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>!<br>
You are <?php echo $_POST["age"]; ?> years old.

    </div> <!--end .entry-->

</div> <!--end #content-->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And I am including the following code from my page which shows the form

```
<form action="http://127.0.0.1:4001/wordpress/script" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
Age: <input type="text" name="age">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This will show the form data in a new page instead of showing the result on the same page.
How can I show the result on same page?

I would like to have something like this:

[image]

Comment: just leave blank the form action

Comment: <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">. Right way to do it.

Comment: @ Murtaza Hussain: no go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `action` attribute from your `form`:

```
<form method="post">
```

**UPDATE**

Now, to keep data on your fields after form submit, just print them on its respective fields:

```
Name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php if (isset($_POST["fname"])) echo $_POST["fname"]; ?>" />
Age: <input type="text" name="age" value="<?php if (isset($_POST["age"])) echo $_POST["age"]; ?>" />
```

Comment: Tried this, but no luck

Comment: @user1128648 try `action="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>"`

Comment: @user1128648 what happens? did your form is submited to another page or what? Tell us the behaviour of your tries.

Comment: @ DontVoteMeDown after submitting the form, it just clearing the filled form data and showing blank form again

Comment: @user1128648 why don't you said before? That is the espected behaviour, to show the values on the fields you need to do more things, look my edit.

Comment: @ DontVoteMeDown : Thanks and sorry for the confusion. This is I am trying to do (see my image ) 1. form field to add name and age 2. after filling data and once I submit, the data should show below the form (just like that second part of attachment ). But When I added the code as per your instruction first time, the data which I entered didnt show up below the form field.

Comment: @user1128648 I got it man, but you asked for how to submit to the same page. We gave you the answer. Show the result is other thing and the easiest part. This now is up to you. You question was answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

this is how it should be

Comment: it just clearing the form data, not retrieving the data from form

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have the result of the form on the same page you have to leave your action empty.
So it is considered as the same page. Your php-file should then contain the validation.

Answer (score 0):

use `bloginfo('url')` to retrieve your site url.

```
<form method='post' action="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wordpress/script">
```

Comment: If you are fetching the form from wordpress admin the `bloginfo('url')` will not work. I don't see the code to fetch data from the admin in your template file. `<?php while(have_posts()):the_post();?>
    <?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile;?>`.I tried the script on my machine (including the line i just added) and it is working great! You can use empty action in form tag!